# Change the backend maxconn in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I have a HAProxy server with global maxconn set to 20000. I would like all backends (there are 60 different frontends based on the route) to have a default of 3000. Is there a way to do this globally?

Relevant code:

```
frontend webapp
    bind 127.0.0.1:8001
    default_backend webapp

backend webapp
server  aa7648e1b884de0afe8491a0e internal-aa7648e1bb60884de0afe8491a0e-1191952057.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:80 maxconn 3000
```

I see the backend for the server is changed but backend default is still 2000 (check screenshot)[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't set `maxconn` for backend (as stated in [docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#4-maxconn)).
Limit of backend sessions is meaningless unless you use `minconn` as answered here:
https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/backend-sessions-limit-200/1661/3

> session limit is only relevant when using minconn:
> https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg26566.html
> As Moemen MHEDHBI explained:
>
> > The Session Limit in the backend row refers to the fullconn parameter of that backend. > > The fullconn is about setting dynamic maxconn on backend servers. You can read more about it in the docs
> > http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4-fullconn 1.7k
> >
> > You need to consider the “fullconn” parameter if you have set up “minconn” in server lines (to use dynamic maxconn), otherwise you can ignore it.